# What's the right Ruby background gem for a continuous background job with pauses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, background, sidekiq

I have an application that needs to poll a huge list of external websites (>10,000 pages, >100 domains) with a given periodicity (e.g. once a day, once a week).

The actual time a webpage should be queried does not need to be met exactly, just that on average a page is polled for a change +/- 20% of the periodicity.
For me this immediately sounded like a background job.

I had a look at gems like Sidekiq, Rescue, Delayed job, but I am not sure if they are really meant to be used for my need. I think the main scheme is a job that is started after an event on the webpage, such as an email being send out after the user registers or a time-consuming calculation that is better pushed to the background.

In my case it feels more like like a schedule followed by a single job, even though the actual polling frequency might change depending on the actual algorithm organizing my website queries.

I thought about having a table looking like this:

```
create_table "websites" do |t|
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "tracking_last_time"
    t.datetime "tracking_next_time"
    t.integer   "tracking_period"
end
```

My background task could now sort the website-list sorting by `tracking_next_time`.

The background task could then:

- see how many seconds/minutes/hours it could sleep
- do so
- wake up by the time it is needed
- query the website
- update the tracking_next_time information and
- see if there are any other queries that might be due.

Since I have a huge amount of websites to query, I might even need more than one background task.

I am thinking that I could start a job for each domain and optimize the http-requests using persistent connections.

In any case, I am not sure if the well-known background gems would fit my needs.
Does anybody have an idea/suggestion?

Comment: Firstly *recommendation* questions are not technically questions on SO. that being said take a look at the [`rufus-scheduler` gem](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). I think your question would fit better if it became more similar to *how can I accomplish this task* and even then please prove that you have tried something first.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what OS you're on. *nix-based systems have a great "periodic task scheduler" built in called `cron` which is ideal for this purpose. You can easily run Rails-based scripts using cron and [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) which have access to the database but don't inflict the long startup or load any of the HTTP/web/front-end processing.

Comment: You probably want to sort by `tracking_last_time + tracking_period` and update `tracking_last_time` when you've successfully processed the page. Then you won't need `tracking_next_time ` at all. You also need a counter for failed attempts and a "site_down" or "do_not_process" flag that is set once the failed attempts exceed a value. Also, use the `head` request to check for page changes and compare that to the `tracking_last_time` value before you request/`get` the page. That reduces the network congestion and speeds up your processing if a page hasn't changed.

Comment: _"Since I have a huge amount of websites to query, I might even need more than one background task"_ -- um yes, generally you split a job up into many tasks. I'd consider one per page (or minimum one per site)

Comment: @engineersmnky: I guess you're right. I wanted to save me some time trying something that is not the right fit. But I guess I'll just try one gem and see how it goes. I'll also have a look at rufus-scheduler. Thanks.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I'm developing on OSX, but I guess the final production machine will be on Linux. I don't really see that CRON would serve my purpose as I don't want to wake up every minute. My background-job might run for 20 minutes without pause and then takes a break for 2h. About your other suggestions: I already introduced some more details like the ones you suggested. I introduced tracking_next_time only to make sorting easier. I tried to sort by a calculation of two columns, but wasn't successful. I will definetly keep the head request in mind. This will save a lot of traffic, thanks!

Comment: Both OS X and Linux have cron. Cron is much more sophisticated than you assume. Intervals beyond a minute are easy, including calculated intervals based on the runtime of an application. It's the core of *nix services and is very flexible.